# Getting rid of /my_custom_post_type/ in the single view URL

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

When I'm reading a custom type post in the single view, I see that the URL is www.my_site.com/my_custom_post_type/title_of_my_post.

How to get rid of this ugly /my_custom_post_type/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
register_post_type( 'my_custom_post_type', array(
    'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => false ),
    // other args
));
```

Make sure you flush your permalinks after changing your code - simply going to Settings > Permalinks is sufficient.

Comment: I'm using Custom Post Type UI plugin and they have only the following options : public, show UI, has archive, capability type, hierarchical, rewrite, custom rewrite slug, query var, menu position, show in menu, supports, built-in taxonomies. I guess what you mention cannot be changed with this plugin :(